# How to enable overflow scrolling within a Semantic Ui Grid?

Tags: css, less, semantic-ui

I don't have enough rep to post images, but here's a link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTp8Q.png

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the proper CSS/LESS to enable sidescrolling here within the Semantic UI framework. There are four columns in this part of the grid, and I need to add four more, but have them hidden off to the right until they are scrolled to, if that makes sense.

```
<div class="features ui grid noMargin">
    <div class="four wide column greyOdd">Stuff here</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyEven">More stuff</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyOdd">Calls n stuff</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyEven">Testing look</div>
</div>
```

How would I add more columns here without them going to the next row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grids elements of Semantic UI got `display: inline-block`, so you can set `white-space:nowrap` to prevent that elements wrap in a row:

```
<div class="features ui grid noMargin" style="overflow-y:auto;white-space:nowrap;">
    <div class="four wide column greyOdd">Stuff here</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyEven">More stuff</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyOdd">Calls n stuff</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyEven">Testing look</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyOdd">Stuff here</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyEven">More stuff</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyOdd">Calls n stuff</div>
    <div class="four wide column greyEven">Testing look</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 3rd July 2017 there is a "scrolling content" style available.
See closing note in https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4335

This makes the entire grid content scroll on overflow. For me this scrolled vertically as I have too much content in single-row columns.

```
<div class="ui grid scrolling content">
```

Modal example:

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="scrolling content">
    <p>Very long content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the same and it worked, but then I tried wrapping the long content in a tab and it broke again :(